# Netbeans remote compile failure, cannot compile on the target

Tags: c++, c, gcc, netbeans

I have a little bit starnge question. Im started to programing Raspi, and i would like to compile my code on the target Pi. If i make it manually i can compile it, but the netbeans(version 8) give me fault for the remote compile. 
gcc -o file file.c -lbcm2835 thats how i need to compile. Or g++.

Here is a little bit codesnap from the output with the error. `[http://codepaste.net/fygdpj][1]`

Please let me allow to ask some help with this situation, oh yes the bcm2835.h is in the /usr/local/include

Regards

Comment: Looks like the linker can't find the bcm2835 library. Are you sure it's there? The header file isn't enough. You need the actual lib.

Comment: im sure , couse if i write it down with my hand it compile the program. :)

Comment: im sure , couse if i write it down with my hand it compile the program. :)
[http://s23.postimg.org/qkvslll57/image.png](Screenshot)

Comment: just added another photo where you can see that [http://s4.postimg.org/9epjr5d2l/pi2.png](Screenshot 2).